# Javascript variable and Web Panel Variable

Tags: javascript, genexus

How do I make the link between the javascript variables and the Web Panel variables?

I have a User Control, and I want to passe the value of a javascript variable to a web panel variable, but I don't know where and how I make that attribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a property of the user control for that.

User control's properties are easily set by asigning a value in your Javascript code. For example:

```
// UC Javascript code - Asigning MyProperty property
this.show = function () {
    var myVar = 1;
    this.MyProperty = myVar;
};
```

Then, you can read the value of the property in your GX code:

```
// GeneXus code - shows a message with "1"
Event Enter
    &MyGxVar = MyUserControl.MyProperty
    msg(&MyGxVar)
EndEvent
```

Comment: It is not working, I always get the default value of the property. Do you have any ideia why this happens?

Comment: This should be working. Can you upload your web application to the cloud using "Deploy to cloud" option (see http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Deploy+to+cloud%3A+Step+by+Step, for more information). Paste the URL in the comments and I'll take a closer look to the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ncardeli! The URL is http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Id899a095c574c049b25f760a574de3016/execute.xml